# Italic or font change for a whole section

Tags: fonts, fontsize, text-manipulation

I would like to change the appearance of a whole section in a text with math content. I have for instance a half page with several equations in it which I would like to be differentiated from the rest of the text by being written in italic or in another font. When I use the command  \textit` for instance the compiler tells me:

```
Paragraph ended before text@command was complete}

Too many }'s }
```

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:
I am writing my master thesis using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\newcommand{\separator}{\begin{center}
\vspace{5mm}
 $* \qquad * \qquad * \qquad * \qquad * \qquad * \qquad * \qquad * \qquad * \qquad * \qquad * \qquad * \qquad * \qquad * \qquad * \qquad *$
\vspace{5mm}
\end{center}}

\separator

Text and equations ...

\separator
```

What I would like is additionally to have everything between separator to be written in a different font or textstyle. I tried putting a `\textit{...}` wrapped all around, but it gave the errors mentioned above.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Well, the error is very clear, you must have left or unintentionally added an extra `}` somewhere. Seeing your code would help find the culprit. If you do a "Find and replace" search for `{` and then for `}`, you'll see the count won't be the same.

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, I understand that. The error comes only when I add the \textit{...} all around, which means that obtaining what I want does not work in that way.

Comment: `\textit{something}` is not the command to use here, use `\itshape` instead, you need to limit the scope using a group But i don't understand your intention here, to be honest.

Comment: @Johannes_B How do I limit the scope using a group? The intention is the following: In these passages I fill in some very calculational details and I personally do not like putting it in appendices because I feel like it breaks continuity. But for people who only want the essentials I want it to be clear what can be ignored. There is a book which does something similar: Quantum Field Theory by Zuber & Itzyskon.

Comment: I would define a new environment for this material, that way it is a group by itself, and you can globally change the appearance. Can you give a visual of that book and the style?

Comment: @Johannes_B -- answer called for.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was writing one up and discovered what i believe to be a bug in a package. When that issue is resolved, i post something. :-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Turns out, it is a *feuture* in amsmath, mail to you and the `mathtools` team about to come.

Answer (score 4):

`\textit` is command that takes an argument, it also is short, meaning you cannot have multiple paragraphs in there. A proper way would be to use `\itshape` and use it in a group, best to define your own environment.

There are many ways to make this material stand out and recognized not to be part of the usual text. Below, i decided to use lines as well as a shift into the margin to make a clear distinction.

[image: loewesimonSuppmat]

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{mathtools}[2015/06/17]
\newenvironment{suppmat}{\begin{addmargin}[1cm]{-1cm}\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.3pt}\smallbreak\itshape}{%
        \smallbreak\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.3pt}\end{addmargin}\medbreak}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{suppmat}
    \begin{equation}
        p=mv
    \end{equation}
    Muss man wissen!
\end{suppmat}
\blindtext
\begin{suppmat}
    This could be some explaining text, we need it to show
    that this stuff can break. \blindtext
    \begin{align}
        E &=mc^2
        \shortintertext{this is short text}
        a^2 + b^2 &= c^2
    \end{align}
\blindtext
\end{suppmat}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Johannes_B was correctly pointing out, `\textit` can only take an argument (e.g. a few written lines) and cannot handle multiple paragraphs.

The simplest solution for me was to use `itshape` as follows:

```
{\itshape
Write here everything that you want in italics. 

It can handle different paragraphs and equations (although the equations will not be in italics)
}
```

Another option is to use `\begingroup \itshape text here will be italics \endgroup` or `\begin{itshape} text here will be in italics \end{itshape}` (Thanks @ChristianHupfer for the suggestion, and mentioning that the last solution works but it's not elegant)

Comment: Although this works, `itshape` is not really an environment. You could use `\begingroup \itshape \endgroup` or a `{ \itshape ....}` as well

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks for the suggestion, I edited the answer